# Extract data with regular expresion with python

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a txt file (see a sample text below) using python. Take into account that the title can be in one single line, split into two lines or even split with a blank line in the middle (TITLE1).

What I would like to achieve is to extract the information to store in a table like this:

| Code | Title | Opening date | Deadline | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-01 | This is the title 1 that is split in two lines with a blank line in the middle | 15-Apr-21 | 26-Aug-21 | EUR 20.00 million |
| TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-02 | This is the title2 in one single line | 15-Mar-21 | 17-Aug-21 | EUR 15.00 million |
| TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-03 | This is the title3 that is too long and takes two lines | 15-May-21 | 26-Sep-21 | EUR 5.00 million |

I manage to identify the "codes titles" with this piece of code:

```
import re

with open('doubt2.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f_contents = f.read() 
    
pattern = re.compile(r'TITLE-.+-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(?!,)\S{1}')
matches = pattern.finditer(f_contents)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

And I get this result:

```
<re.Match object; span=(160, 188), match='TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-01:'>
<re.Match object; span=(669, 697), match='TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-02;'>
<re.Match object; span=(1066, 1094), match='TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-03:'>
```

My doubt is how to get the information that I identified with the regular expression and extract the rest of the data. Can you help me, please?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam id diam
> posuere, eleifend diam at, condimentum justo. Pellentesque mollis a
> diam id consequat.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-01: This is the title 1 that
>
> is split into two lines with a blank line in the middle
>
> Conditions Pellentesque blandit scelerisque pellentesque. Sed nec quam
> purus. Quisque nec tellus sed neque accumsan lacinia sit amet sit amet
> tellus. Etiam venenatis nibh vel pellentesque elementum. Nullam eget
> tortor quam. Morbi sed leo et arcu aliquet luctus.
>
> Opening date 15 Apr 2021
>
> Deadline 26 Aug 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 20.00 million.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-02; This is the title2 in one single line
>
> Conditions Cras egestas consectetur sapien at dignissim. Maecenas
> commodo purus nibh, a tempus augue vestibulum feugiat. Vestibulum
> dolor neque, sagittis ut tortor et, lobortis faucibus quam.
>
> Opening date 15 March 2021
>
> Deadline 17 Aug 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 15.00 million.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-03: This is the title3 that is too long and takes two lines
>
> Conditions Cras egestas consectetur sapien at dignissim. Maecenas
> commodo purus nibh, a tempus augue vestibulum feugiat. Vestibulum
> dolor neque, sagittis ut tortor et, lobortis faucibus quam.
>
> Opening date 15 May 2021
>
> Deadline 26 Sep 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 5.00 million.

Comment: Use `pattern.findall()`, it will return a list of strings.

Comment: How can you tell that a title is split over 2 lines?

Comment: Please post the table as text, not a screenshot. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Is `Conditions` always the beginning of the first paragraph after the title? You can match across multiple lines until that, using the `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` flags.

Comment: @Thefourthbird The text I am using is that way, some titles are in a single line, other titles are split in two lines or even split with a blank like in the middle

Comment: @Barmar could you give me an example? With mi regular expression I find only the code, but I don't know how to extract that information and how identify the rest of the information I need (Opening date, Deadline, Budget..)

Comment: This for example will get you all the values https://regex101.com/r/ZE0U6z/1 see https://ideone.com/LticIi

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for the indications. I wish I knew that regex101.com website before, it took me two days to learn that basic regular expression. Still, I have to check how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with capturing groups. USe the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.*` to match across multiple lines, so you can capture multi-line titles. And use lazy quantifiers to avoid the matches being too long.

```
import csv
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(TITLE-.+?-\d{2}-\d{2})\S*\s*(.*?)^Conditions.*?^Opening date (\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*?^Deadline (\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*^Indicative budget:.*?(EUR [\d.]+ \w+)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
matches = pattern.finditer(f_contents)

with open("result.csv", "w") as outfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvfile.writerow(['Code', 'Title', 'Opening date', 'Deadline', 'Budget'])
    for match in matches:
        csvfile.writerow([match.group(1), match.group(2).replace('\n', ' '), match.group(3), match.group(4), match.group(5)])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5mZSDf/1)

Comment: that is impressive... thank you very much. I tried your code and it tells me that  ```module 'csv' has no attribute 'writerow'``` Do I need to install a special package?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `csvfile.writerow`

Comment: thank you again. Just a minor mistake, instead of `matches = patter.finditer(f_contents)` it would be `matches = pattern.finditer(f_contents)`

Comment: The code only works for the first TITLE. The result.csv only contains a single row

Comment: I was missing a `?` in one of the lazy quantifiers. Also, I didn't notice that some dates have full months instead of 3-letter abbreviations.

Comment: Why is the text so inconsistent in its formatting? If it's written by a human instead of computer, you're going to drive yourself crazy trying to deal with all the possible typos.

Comment: I tried to replicate the inconsistency on the text that I am facing... It was an example, because I need to extract even more data but I did not want to make the question harder. I think the key for me is to understand how to create that complex regular expression, for instance using regex101.com Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: www.regular-expression.info

Comment: It's like any other programming, you have to learn the basic pieces and then figure out how to combine them for your needs. There's no magic bullet.

Comment: @Barmar How can I test the regular expression you propose? I tried to replicate it in my real text (the text I put was a sample), using regex101 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the real text doesn't follow the same pattern as the sample you gave. I told you that you'll have trouble if the text is human generated and not consistent.

Comment: @Barmar The text is kind of consistent, at least the part I need to extract follows a pattern with some minor differences. The first problem I face is that the real text is a PDF, so I transform the PDF to txt and during the transformation, it alters the structure a little bit. Could I give you a example of the real text to have a look on it?

Comment: @Barmar But even if I take the sample text of the question, and your regular expression `^(TITLE-.+?-\d{2}-\d{2})\S*\s*(.*?)^Conditions.*?^Opening date (\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*?^Deadline (\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*^Indicative budget:.*?(EUR [\d.]+ \w+)` it doesn't work on regex101.com. I think it is related to re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL

Comment: `re.DOTALL` is called `single line` on regex101.com

Comment: @Barmar Here you can see the real example: https://regex101.com/r/aJQgAI/1/ 
You can see that the problem is that in a few cases, there is one or several `\n` after 'Opening date', 'Deadline' or 'Indicative budget'. Could you have a look? It should find 77 matches

Comment: If it's not always a single space, use `\s+` to match any whitespace, which will match newlines.

Comment: @Barmar this is the approch I am following: instead of using a big selection with several groups I am doing several selections. I didn't manage to make it better but it works. You can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048123/how-to-add-information-found-with-regular-expressions-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

You could get the matches using capture groups.

Note that you can write `(?!,)\S` as `[^\s,]`

Based on the lines in the example:

```
^(TITLE-.+?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[^\s,] (.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)(?:\r?\n(?!Opening).*)*\r?\nOpening date (\d+ .*)(?:\r?\n(?!Deadline).*)*\r?\nDeadline (\d+ .*)(?:\r?\n(?!Indicative budget:).*)*\r?\nIndicative budget: .*?(EUR \d+(?:\.\d+)? \w+)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `(TITLE-.+?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` Capture **group 1**, match the title part
- `[^\s,]`  Match any non whitespace char except a comma
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)` Capture **group 2**, match all lines that do not start with an uppercase char
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Opening).*)*\r?\nOpening date`  Match all lines till *Opening date*
- `(\d+ .*)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ digits, a space and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Deadline).*)*\r?\nDeadline`  Match all lines until *Deadline*
- `(\d+ .*)` Capture **group 4**, match 1+ digits and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Indicative budget:).*)*\r?\nIndicative budget: .*?` Match all lines until *Indicative budget:*
- `(EUR \d+(?:\.\d+)? \w+)` Capture **group 5**, match EUR, the number and 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4lKQo1/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LticIi)

Then you could for example load it in a table or dataframe

```
with open('doubt2.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r"^(TITLE-.+?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[^\s,] (.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)(?:\r?\n(?!Opening).*)*\r?\nOpening date (\d+ .*)(?:\r?\n(?!Deadline).*)*\r?\nDeadline (\d+ .*)(?:\r?\n(?!Indicative budget:).*)*\r?\nIndicative budget: .*?(EUR \d+(?:\.\d+)? \w+)", re.MULTILINE)
    matches = pattern.findall(f_contents)
    df = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns = ['Code', 'Title', 'Opening date', 'Deadline', 'Budget'])
    df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('[\r\n]+',' ')
    print(df)
```

*Output*

```
            Code          Title   Opening date     Deadline         Budget
0  TITLE-SDFS...  This is th...    15 Apr 2021  26 Aug 2021  EUR 20.00 ...
1  TITLE-SDFS...  This is th...  15 March 2021  17 Aug 2021  EUR 15.00 ...
2  TITLE-SDFS...  This is th...    15 May 2021  26 Sep 2021  EUR 5.00 m...
```

Comment: thank you again. I know that comments are not for this, but it doesn't allow me to mark the solution as useful. Thank you for the website regex101.com

Comment: OK... I have to learn also how to manage this website :) I will accept both solutions

Comment: @nekovolta You can not accept both, but if the other solution works for you that is perfectly ok.

Comment: I didn't know I can not accept both solutions. I like both of them, but maybe the other solution fits better because of the CSV file generation. However, I understood better the regular expression with your explanation. I am impressed

Comment: @nekovolta From 15 reputation points you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answers that you consider useful.

Comment: Why did you put a `?` in this expresion? `(TITLE-.+?-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})`

Comment: @nekovolta The `?` makes the `.*` non greedy (lazy) to match as least as possible characters before it matches `-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`