# How to add information found with regular expressions in a CSV file

Tags: python, regex, csv, regex-group

I am trying to "append" new information to a CSV file. The problem is that that information is not in a dataframe structure, but is information extracted from a text using regular expressions. The sample text would be the next one:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam id diam
> posuere, eleifend diam at, condimentum justo. Pellentesque mollis a
> diam id consequat.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-01: This is the title 1 that
>
> is split into two lines with a blank line in the middle
>
> Conditions Pellentesque blandit scelerisque pellentesque. Sed nec quam
> purus. Quisque nec tellus sed neque accumsan lacinia sit amet sit amet
> tellus. Etiam venenatis nibh vel pellentesque elementum. Nullam eget
> tortor quam. Morbi sed leo et arcu aliquet luctus.
>
> Opening date 15 Apr 2021
>
> Deadline 26 Aug 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 20.00 million.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-02; This is the title2 in one single line
>
> Conditions Cras egestas consectetur sapien at dignissim. Maecenas
> commodo purus nibh, a tempus augue vestibulum feugiat. Vestibulum
> dolor neque, sagittis ut tortor et, lobortis faucibus quam.
>
> Opening date 15 March 2021
>
> Deadline 17 Aug 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 15.00 million.
>
> TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-03: This is the title3 that is too long and takes
> two lines
>
> Conditions Cras egestas consectetur sapien at dignissim. Maecenas
> commodo purus nibh, a tempus augue vestibulum feugiat. Vestibulum
> dolor neque, sagittis ut tortor et, lobortis faucibus quam.
>
> Opening date 15 May 2021
>
> Deadline 26 Sep 2021
>
> Indicative budget: The total indicative budget for the topic is EUR
> 5.00 million.

To extract all the information, I have to make several interactions to extract the information I need. I know it is possible to make just one iteration subdividing into several groups what I need, but it is very hard for me to find just a regular expression that works. Instead, I am using several of them:

```
import re
import csv
    
with open('doubt2.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f_contents = f.read()

regexHOR =r'\n(TITLE-\S+-\d{2}-\d{2})[:|;](.*?)^Conditions'
regexOD = r'^Opening date\s+(\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*?'
regexDL =r'^Deadline\s+(\d+ \w+ \d+)'

patternHOR = re.compile(regexHOR, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
patternOD = re.compile(regexOD, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
patternDL = re.compile(regexDL, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

matchesHOR = patternHOR.finditer(f_contents)
matchesOD = patternOD.finditer(f_contents)
matchesDL = patternDL.finditer(f_contents)
```

`marchesHOR` finds two groups, whereas the other matches are just one group. Once I have the matches I have to export it in a CSV file executing the next code:

```
with open("result.csv", "w",newline='') as outfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvfile.writerow(['Topic ID', 'Title', 'Opening date', 'Deadline'])
    for match in matchesHOR:
        csvfile.writerow([match.group(1), match.group(2).replace('\n', ' '),'',''])
    for match in matchesOD:
        csvfile.writerow(['','',match.group(1),''])
    for match in matchesDL:
        csvfile.writerow(['','','',match.group(1)])
```

The problem is that when I write the new nows after the `matchesHOR` it put me below, as you can see in this table:

| CODE | TITLE | Opening | Deadline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE 1 | TITLE 1 |  |  |
| CODE 2 | TITLE 2 |  |  |
| CODE 3 | TITLE 3 |  |  |
|  |  | OPENING 1 |  |
|  |  | OPENING 2 |  |
|  |  | OPENING 3 |  |
|  |  |  | DEADLINE 1 |
|  |  |  | DEADLINE 2 |
|  |  |  | DEADLINE 3 |

*Any additional comment to perform the four interaction to identify the several groups are welcome*

Comment: Can't you combine all regex in one and use *named group* `(?P<name>...)` instead?

Comment: Can you post the content of `regexHOR` and others?

Comment: @IronFist I don't understand how to combine the names as you suggested. I'll try to add more information to the question to make it clear

Comment: @IoaTzimas might you help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rearrange things a bit so that all items are written for a row at the same time. The approach here is to use the `match_hor` to find each title start, and to then use this as a starting point for the `match_od`, which is in turn used as a starting point for the `match_dl`.

```
import re
import csv
    
with open('doubt2.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f_contents = f.read()

regexHOR = r'\n(TITLE-\S+-\d{2}-\d{2})[:|;](.*?)^Conditions'
regexOD = r'^Opening date\s+(\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})\s*?'
regexDL =r'^Deadline\s+(\d+ \w+ \d+)'

patternHOR = re.compile(regexHOR, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
patternOD = re.compile(regexOD, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
patternDL = re.compile(regexDL, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

with open("result.csv", "w",newline='') as outfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvfile.writerow(['Topic ID', 'Title', 'Opening date', 'Deadline'])
    
    for match_hor in patternHOR.finditer(f_contents):
        code, title = [match_hor.group(1), match_hor.group(2).replace('\n', ' ')]
        offset = match_hor.end()
        
        match_od = patternOD.search(f_contents[offset:])
        offset += match_od.end()
        opening = match_od.group(1)
        
        match_dl = patternDL.search(f_contents[offset:]) 
        offset += match_dl.end()
        deadline = match_dl.group(1)
        
        csvfile.writerow([code, title.strip(), opening, deadline])
```

This would give you `result.csv` containing:

```
Topic ID,Title,Opening date,Deadline
TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-01,This is the title 1 that  is split into two lines with a blank line in the middle,15 Apr 2021,26 Aug 2021
TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-02,This is the title2 in one single line,15 March 2021,17 Aug 2021
TITLE-SDFSD-DFDS-SFDS-01-03,This is the title3 that is too long and takes two lines,15 May 2021,26 Sep 2021
```

Comment: It is almost what I need. But if you see, the deadline column is always *26 Aug 2021* but if you check the original text, the deadline is different in the three cases. Why is this?

Comment: The second offset also needed to be added, it was starting the search at the wrong point

Comment: I still need to understand what is doing the procedure: `match_dl = patternDL.search(f_contents[match_hor.end() + match_od.end():]) `, mainly what is between brackets

Comment: `f_contents` is the entire text. So instead of passing the whole text to the search, just pass a slice starting at the offset where the last searches finished. See [`start` and `end'](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.match.end)

Comment: In my real problem, I have to add a sixth column that is `match_con = patternCON.search(f_contents[match_hor.end() + match_od.end() + match_dl.end() + match_bg.end():])` and after that line `contribution = match_con.group(1)` but I always get the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Comment: It means your `match_con` search failed returning `None`

Comment: I understand the error now. The `patternCON` is before the pattern `match_bg.end()` so if I put the `patternCON` after the other search if doesn't found anything. But I still do not manage to understand why. I mean, if I put `match_con = patternCON.search(f_contents[match_hor.end() + match_od.end() + match_dl.end():])` before `match_bg = patternBG.search(f_contents[match_hor.end() + match_od.end() + match_dl.end() + match_con.end():])` it works, and that is because the matches based on `patternCON` are ordered before `patternBG` but why?

Comment: I suggest you add some print statements to help you visualise what is happening. If you are adding more searches, I suggest you add an `offset = 0` variable and then just `+=` each `.end()` as you go

Comment: Could you give me an example of using `offset = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

I propose to you the following code, using [positive lookahead, lookbehind and namedgroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), as below:

```
>>> regexHOR = r'(?P<TopicID>TITLE-\S+-\d{2}-\d{2})[:;]\s*(?P<Title>[\w\s]+(?=Conditions))'
>>>
>>> regexOD = r'(?P<OpeningDate>(?<=Opening date )\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4})'
>>>
>>> regexDL = r'(?P<DeadLine>(?<=Deadline )\d+ \w+ \d+)'
>>>
>>>regex_pattern = re.compile('.*?'.join([regexHOR, regexOD, regexDL]), re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
>>>
>>> for match in re.finditer(regex_pattern, f_contents):
        csvfile.writerow([match.group('TopicID'), match.group('Title'), \
        match.group('OpeningDate'), match.group('DeadLine')])
```

Each time you call `csvfile.writerow`, a new row is written, that's why you don't have all items of each loop iteration written on the same row.